# Haskell Module "Main" already loaded

Tags: haskell

Every time I try to load my file i get the error "Module "Main" already loaded".
The file i am trying to load loads another module, the module loads by itself fine.
The file only loads that module and nothing else.
Can anyone tell me why it is giving me this error?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the first few lines of all the files involved, their filenames/directory structure, and a log from the console or ghci (wherever this problem you're describing is manifesting)?

Comment: http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/craft2e/errors/allErrors.html ?

Comment: Not enough information.

Answer (score 4):

This is a Hugs error, and honestly my first recommendation would be to switch to GHC. Is there a particular reason you're using Hugs?

However, if you don't want to or can't switch, [this page](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/craft2e/errors/allErrors.html) says the following:

> This error happens if you load two anonymous modules into (Win)Hugs. The solution is to name the modules concerned and to set up the appropriate import/export structures.

You can use [this page](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/modules.html) as a guide for setting up the module names and import/export structures.

Comment: +1 for recommending GHC over Hugs.  Hugs has been deprecated and has had no development for several years.